# unhandled exception: unsupported operation: cannot modify unmodifiable map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an entity for data processing. But there is a problem, I want to write some data in a folder and then save it. To then send this data via API. I made a map and I want to save the data. But I can't because of this problem. Here is my code: If someone tells me where my problem is I will be grateful)

```html
 
part 'addition_entity.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class AdditionEntity with _$AdditionEntity {
  const AdditionEntity._();

  const factory AdditionEntity({
    required AdditionModel additionModel,
    @Default([])   List<Map<String,String>> selectedVariants,
    @Default({})   Map<String,String> mySelected,
    @Default(false) final bool progress,
    @Default(true) final bool enabled,
  }) = _AdditionEntity;



  AdditionEntity copyWithSelected(AdditionVariantModel selectedAdditionVariant){
    bool selected = false;
    var currentLevel = 0;
    var currentIndex = 0;
    while(selected == false){
      if(currentLevel == 0) {
        if(additionModel.variants!.contains(selectedAdditionVariant)){
            mySelected['additionid'] = additionModel.id!;
            mySelected['aditionVariontid'] = selectedAdditionVariant.id!;
            mySelected['level']= currentLevel.toString();
           selectedVariants.add(mySelected);
         selected = true;
         currentLevel++;
        } else {
          currentLevel ++;
        }
      } else {
        //if(additionModel.variants[currentIndex])
        currentLevel++;
    }
    }
    return AdditionEntity( additionModel: selectedAdditionVariant.addition! );
  }

 
}
```

Error:

```html
E/flutter ( 5976): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable map
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples on what you tried or what you expect to cause the error?

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime error in line "mySelected ['additionid'] = additionModel.id !;" . I just want to add this data to the map, so add all the data to the map array. But the problem arises! and I can't do anything.\

Comment: Did you run the build_runner to generate the freezed code? flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

Comment: @maxmitz Yes) I run this command